# Csv files and giving dictionary certain keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv

I have a Csv file with temperatures in Celsius. Like this:

```
17;15;13;13;12;13;14;15;15;16;17;18;19;21;23;25;25;23;22;22;21;19;18;18
```

Each number is the temperature at X hour of the day, the csv is ordered.. 
Now I want to give each entry a key, like this:

```
{0: 17, 1: 15, 2:13, 3: 13, 4: 12, ... 23: 18}
```

Yes Im not using AM / PM time format, I know how to read the csv file and return it as a list of dictionaries, my problem is how to give it certain keys.

```
def read_temp(file_csv):
    import csv
    with open('file_csv', 'rU') as file_csv:
         reader = csv.DictReader(file_csv)
         result = []
         for d in reader:
              result.append(d)
    return result
```

I could do it with fieldnames = ['0' , '1', '2', '3, '4', '5',... '23'], but it's not really the best way, imagine i have to do it for 100 keys...

Does someone know a better way? Ty in advance.

Comment: If the temperature is ordered and the key to be given is 0,1,2,3... why not put them into a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use numeric keys like the example you gave, try this:

```
result = {}   # a dictionary, not a list
for idx, d in enumerate(reader):
    result[idx] = d
```

The [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function will give you `idx` starting from 0 along with each data item `d`.

But I think @SilentMonk is right - the existing code you have lets you access `result[0]` just fine.

**Edit** I took another look at [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).  Try this:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(file_csv, fieldnames=range(24))
```

with the rest of your code staying the same.  That should give you what you expect.  `range(24)` produces the list [0, 1, ..., 23].  The 24 values in each row of the file will be given the respective keys from 0 to 23.

Comment: Yea it works, and i was missing  delimiter = ';' on the csv.DictReader.

Comment: @EXT Glad to hear it! :)

Comment: Btw the values are strings, how can i change them to ints?

Comment: Before `result.append(d)`, `d = {k:int(v) for k,v in d.iteritems()}`

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to just zip them with a `range(24)` e.g.:

```
>>> temps = "17;15;13;13;12;13;14;15;15;16;17;18;19;21;23;25;25;23;22;22;21;19;18;18".split(";")
>>> temps
['17', '15', '13', '13', '12', '13', '14', '15', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '21', '23', '25', '25', '23', '22', '22', '21', '19', '18', '18']
>>> zip(range(24),temps)
[(0, '17'), (1, '15'), (2, '13'), (3, '13'), (4, '12'), (5, '13'), (6, '14'), (7, '15'), (8, '15'), (9, '16'), (10, '17'), (11, '18'), (12, '19'), (13, '21'), (14, '23'), (15, '25'), (16, '25'), (17, '23'), (18, '22'), (19, '22'), (20, '21'), (21, '19'), (22, '18'), (23, '18')]
>>> dict(zip(range(24),temps))
{0: '17', 1: '15', 2: '13', 3: '13', 4: '12', 5: '13', 6: '14', 7: '15', 8: '15', 9: '16', 10: '17', 11: '18', 12: '19', 13: '21', 14: '23', 15: '25', 16: '25', 17: '23', 18: '22', 19: '22', 20: '21', 21: '19', 22: '18', 23: '18'}
>>>
```